# Regex find not working in SSMS query window?

Tags: regex, find, ssms-2005

I'm trying to find the next `BEGIN` or `END` without missing any, so I want to search with a regex in the find. I want to find the next `BEGIN` or `END`.

For some reason it's not working. What's wrong with what I am doing?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSMS (and Visual Studio too) uses a CRAZY Regex flavor, and it's always a huge pain to use.  I CAN'T BELIEVE they don't use the .NET Regex engine!

[Here's the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx), which you should definitely bookmark if you ever plan on using Regex again.

The Regex you should use is:

```
<(begin|end)>
```

Unusual keys:
`<` beginning of a word
`>` end of word
`()` group -- however, for capturing (and replacing), you must use `{}`

You can also see a quick-list of "special characters" by clicking the little <kbd>></kbd> button that appears to the right of the text box. This is basically a built-in cheat-sheet.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link too!

Comment: The {} vs () for capture/replace is absolutely crazy! Thanks for the tip.